# Finding the permutations of a string using Stack in java?

Tags: java, iteration

I need to find the permutations of a string in Java, for example "abc" will be "abc" "acb" "bac" "bca" "cab" "cba" and return the number of said permutations.
My code is looking like this right now:

```
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Vector;

public static Vector<String> permIter( String u ) { // u not empty
  Vector<String> p = new Vector<String>();
 int n = u.length(), k;
 Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();
 Stack<Integer> t = new Stack<Integer>();
 s.push (u); t.push(0);
do {
k = t.pop(); t.push(k);
 if ( k == n-1 ) {
     p.add( u );
} else {
  t.push(k+1); 
  for (int i=k+1; i<n; i=i+1) {
   String v = u.substring( 0, k ) + u.substring( i, i+1 ) + u.substring( k+1, i )
                                  + u.substring( k, k+1 ) + u.substring( i+1, n );
    p.add(v); 
   } 
   s.pop(); 
  }
 } while ( !s.empty() );
  return p;
}
```

The problem is that when I take a string, let's say "abc", the code skips the second permutation with the same beginning letter and instead of counting 6 permutations, it counts 3.
Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: If all you want to know is the number of permutations, there's a simple formula...

Comment: @Gardener I tried but it's still not working, thanks tho